# Display day name in TextBox from the date I have selected in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, formatting, datetimepicker

I'm current using the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    DateTime c = a.Value.AddDays(1) ;
    textBox1.Text = c.ToString("dd--MM-yyyy"); 
}
```

and I get a result that looks like the following in my TextBox:

> 08--01-2015

How can show the day of the week of the date in my TextBox?

Comment: [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx)? Or does it need to match the culture settings of the user?

Comment: What do you want as a result exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> no actually i want it like |Thursday 08--01-2015|

Use "dddd" in your ToString() call:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = a.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd dd--MM-yyyy");
    }
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.